# Connect Netbeans to Oracle SQL (Remote Host) raises Exception

Tags: oracle, netbeans

I'm Trying to connect Netbeans 11.3 to remote Oracle SQL database through Services.
The problem is not in the credentials since it is working in sql developer with exactly the same data.
I'm not sure what is the problem. But I've tried different ojdbc versions, and it keeps raising an error.

[image]
(Some parts are hidden due to security reasons).

Comment: The OCI driver needs a complete Oracle client installation. Do you have that? But why do you use OCI anyway? The thin driver is the recommended one (which does not need a native DLL). SQL Developer also uses the thin driver by default

Comment: I did changed it to thin driver and it worked. Thank you very much!